# "Рубашка игральной карты" українською?

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Як буде "рубашка карты" українською? Можна скалькувати як "сорочка карти", чи "тильна сторона", але цікаво чи це правильний переклад.

Додатковий контекст -- фраза "рубашкой вверх".

Comment: [Рубашка карты – соро́чка на ка́рті, спи́нка ка́рти.](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)

Comment: @Yola Схоже на ½ відповідї, можете перенести з відписів до відповідї.

Comment: Мабуть, обкладинка.

Answer (score 3):

Я би казав "зворот" карти. Відповідно, "рубашкой вверх" — зворотом догори. "Сорочка карти" — варіант, який я в українській не зустрічав. Думаю, то чисто російська ідіома.